# Text expansion in Diablo III fullscreen on OS X

Tags: diablo-iii, macos

My usual [text expander](http://lifehacker.com/5749631/the-mac-text-expansion-face-off), Typinator, doesn't work when *Diablo III* is in fullscreen. How can I expand text in *D3*—is there anything built-in, or should another OS X text expansion utility work?

Comment: "What other OS X text expansion utility will let me..." this feels like a shopping recommendation. I'd stick to just asking if you can expand text in D3.

Comment: Does it work with other Blizzard games? This seems more like a question for Blizzard support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried the trial version of [TextExpander](http://www.smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/screencast/index.html) and it seems to work in *StarCraft II* in fullscreen.  I don't have *Diablo III* beta access so I can't truly say if it'll work… but since they're both Blizzard games, the chances are high.

Comment: Completely revisited my answer after some tests.